# DQL Documentum count with multi values

Tags: dql, documentum, documentum-dql

**select c_currency, count(r_object_id) from table group by c_currency**

c_currency is multi value

erreur :

```
the DQL statement has aggregation function on lightweight repeating attribute , the clause can only have r_object_id
```

But when i add r_object_id in groupe by i dont have any row result!

Hepl!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `ROW_BASED DQL` hint?

```
select c_currency, count(*) from table group by c_currency enable(ROW_BASED)
```